# Trying to add Conditional Statemnt

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, algebra

I'm new to coding so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Why isn't the following code working?

I currently have int x = 100 and boolean b = false

```
if ( x == b)
{
    System.out.println(x + " is equal to " + b);
}
else
{
    System.out.println(x + "is not equal to " + b);
}
```

I expect the output to be "100 is not equal to false"

Comment: You will get a compilation exception, because you compare two variable which are not the same type, Java is not like other languages which ignore the type, java is a typique language

Comment: And what do you get? Do you get your expected outcome or something else?

Comment: The code doesn't compile on `x == b`.

Comment: You are getting a compiler error because you are not using the operator `==` to compare the same types of primitives - one is an int and the other is a boolean.

Comment: The error is saying: The operator ==  is undefined for the argument types int, boolean

Comment: @Dys Because you cannot compare `int` to `boolean`, it just is not allowed in Java.  They are primitive types.

Comment: Java is a strong statically-typed language. `int` and `boolean` are different types and no conversion will be made to make them comparable. Some languages (for example, C++) can regard a `boolean` as `1` when `true`, and `0` when `false`. If that's what you were implying, you have to do this on your own. `System.out.println(x + " is " + (x == (b ? 1 : 0) ? " " : "not ") +"equal to " + b);`

Answer (score -7):

Sorry, late in the day. Got my logic backwards twice.

A 1 or any positive integer will be true. Think binary - 0 or 1.

The comparison is Boolean so 1 or 100 = true.

Comment: Are you saying you can compare `int =1` to `boolean = true` and it would be `true`?  You can't compare 2 different primitive types.

Comment: This may the case for languages that implicitly convert integers to booleans. This is not the case for Java IIRC.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Clarified my comment--I am not asserting that such a conversion is a sufficient condition, only that it is a necessary one. My intent isn't to assert that this answer is the case for any language, just that it definitely isn't right for java (also late in the day and fried brain, just like the first line of the answer :( )

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem You can do `var b = true` and `var x = 1` and compare them with `==` in Javascript, but in that case they are both `var` anyway and you are not using `===`.  So not quite the same.

Comment: As you can see, he is not showing data types in code, only saying it in text. I am assuming loose typing. Otherwise the question makes no sense anyhow. It also doesn't say Java. I get that it sure looks like Java. But yeah that would give the error 'incomparable types: int and boolean' in Java. BTW, it will work in loosely typed languages like VB.NET.

Comment: "_he is not showing data types_" The question states "_I currently have int x = 100 and boolean b = false_". And the question is "_Why **isn't** the following code working?_". Your answer claims that it is.

Comment: The question is tagged Java so they _did_ specify the language. And in Java you cannot compare a boolean with an integer. Your answer is simply wrong which is the most justified reason to downvote. I didn't downvote myself (I think -4 is already enough), but I definitely agree with them.